# Calculate average of last rolling four weeks

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

So I got to this point where I have this table and I want to add the average values for the last rolling four weeks.

[image]

To get something like this.

[image]

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions:

```
avg(input) over (order by date rows between 1 preceding and 4 preceding) as prev_avg_4
```

Answer (score 0):

I did the following:

```
CREATE TABLE Test (
 DateRecorded datetime,
 SampleValue int,
 AvgValue float,
);

DECLARE @Now DATETIME = SYSDATETIME();
DECLARE @AvgLast4Hours FLOAT;

SET @AvgLast4Hours =
    (SELECT AVG(Cast(SampleValue as Float)) from Test
    WHERE DateRecorded BETWEEN DATEADD(HOUR, -4, @Now) AND @Now)

INSERT INTO Test VALUES
(@Now, 23, @AvgLast4Hours)
```

I used SQL SERVER maybe you'll need to do some adjusting like changing the SYSDATETIME function for your database function. Also, I used an interval of 4 hours, change it for what you need.